# INotifyPropertyChaned & RealProxy

Tags: c#, .net, inotifypropertychanged

I use RealProxy to implement INotifyPropertyChanged.
But I have a issue with the inner calls to the INPC property.
For example, I don't have NotifyChanged event when I calling ChangeStatus method. But I have this event when I assign this property in the external context. How can intercept inner calls?

```
public class Order : MarshalByRefObject, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    [NotifyProperty]
    public bool Status {get;set;}

    public void ChangeStatus(bool status)
    {
        Status = status;
    }
}

public class Test
{
    public void Test()
    {
         var order = CreateTransparentProxyWithINPC<Order>();
         order.Status = true;//all good
         order.ChangeStatus(dalse);//dont'have notify event
    }
}
```

Comment: Presumably that's because although `ChangeStatus` itself is proxied, by the time you've got through to the implementation of `ChangeStatus`, you're in the "real" original code. You really need the property itself to do this, I think. IL rewriting feels like a better solution than RealProxy for this.

Comment: What is the `CreateTransparentProxyWithINPC<T>`?

Comment: Jon Skeet, ok. How can I use IL injection without PostSharp? If I will use TypeBuilder then I breake Order contract...

Comment: Hamlet Hakobyan, this is RealProxy implementation.